# Play Store won't allow installing both flavors of my app

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I am getting "Can't install " dialog when trying to install from Play Store while the other flavor is already installed.

I have two flavors: free and paid. Both have different applicationIds like so:

```
free {
  applicationId "aaa.bbb.ccc.free"
}

paid {
  applicationId "aaa.bbb.ccc.paid"
}
```

I can't install Free if Paid is installed and vice-versa.

In the code I essentially use the main-flavor for the paid version and add advertisment stuff in the free flavor.

FreeActivity1 inherits Activity1 and
FreeActivity2 inherits from Activity2

My main manifest (used in paid flavor):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="aaa.bbb.ccc"
      android:sharedUserId="aaa.bbb.ccc">
...
<application ...>
    <activity
            android:name=".Activity1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity-alias
            android:name="${applicationId}.act1"
            android:targetActivity=".Activity1"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".ddd.Activity2"/>
    <activity-alias
            android:name="${applicationId}.act2"
            android:targetActivity=".ddd.Activity2"/>
</application>
```

and my free manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="aaa.bbb.ccc"
      android:sharedUserId="aaa.bbb.ccc">

<application tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
            android:name=".FreeActivity1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
            tools:replace="android:targetActivity"
            android:name="${applicationId}.act1"
            android:targetActivity=".FreeActivity1"/>

    <activity
            tools:node="remove"
            android:name=".Activity1"
    />

    <activity
            android:name=".ddd.FreeActivity2"/>

    <activity-alias
            tools:replace="android:targetActivity"
            android:name="${applicationId}.act2"
            android:targetActivity=".ddd.FreeActivity2"/>

    <activity
            tools:node="remove"
            android:name=".ddd.Activity2"
    />
...
</application>
```

I have 2 Apps in the Play Console and released just fine but one of my features is migrating the user settings from the free to the paid version. As it is, I just cannot install both on the same device via Google Play. It works fine with apk install.

Tangentially related maybe(?): I have two google accounts with Play Store access. On **one** of those accounts, Play Store tells me, my Pro version is not compatible with my device (Same device I use on other account). I  use the same features/permissions (internet) for free and paid.

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I have debugged the playstore installation with logcat. I get the following error:

> Error -505 while installing aaa.bbb.ccc.free: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/aaa.bbb.ccc.freeXXXXXXXXXXXX: Package aaa.bbb.ccc.free has no signatures that match those in shared user aaa.bbb.ccc; ignoring!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your package name is the same in your manifest for both paid and free. Try changing it there.

Comment: I have decompiled my apks and both manifests have the applicationId in the package attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is actually a pretty bad problem:

I used sharedUserId and Google App Signing together. This is just not possible (see edit in op) and there are 0 warnings in the Play Console.

Since the automatic signing process always generates a new key for each App in the Store, those signatures will not match but Play Store requires them to if they have the same sharedUserId.

Either I remove all features requiring the sharedUserId or I unpublish both my apps and create two new versions with different applicationId and use manual signing.